# tToogle() в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Добрый день, не могу сообразить как сделать `toggleClass()` в **Angular** 
Есть 2 блока

```
<div id="news"></div><div id="application></div>"
```

и есть кнопка

```
<button class="btn">
```

Не пойму как в ангуляре сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку у

```
<div id="news">
```

добавлялся класс к примеру `hidden` а у

```
<div id="application">
```

убирался

Comment: У вас вопрос по `AngularJs` или `Angular 2`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляет класс если условие true

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hidden':true}"></div>
```

Скрывает блок если условие false

```
<div *ngIf="true"></div>
```

Comment: не очень понял ваш ответ но дали подсказку в какую сторону искать спасибо=)

Comment: или `<div [class.hidden]="!show"></div><button class="btn" (click)="show = !show">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="news" ng-show="hidden">1</div>
<div id="application" ng-hide="hidden">2</div>
<button class="btn" ng-click="hidden = !hidden">
```

Советую почитать документацию по [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), еще лучше почитать ответ, с [JQuery на Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: Мне кажется, вопрос по `Angular 2`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, В вопросе написано Angular.

Comment: Гммм.. А метка `Angular2` стоит))

Comment: да интересует Angular2 я только только начал с ним работать, что то и не думал что подумают про первый=) я так понял для второго ответ не подойдет